# tar command not found on rhel6

Tags: rhel, tar, docker

I am trying to download a file in rhel6 and use tar to uncompress it. I am running this on docker. I get a wierd error saying :

```
/bin/sh: tar: command not found
2014/12/22 19:32:21 The command [/bin/sh -c tar -xzvf dse-4.0.3-bin.tar.gz] returned a non-zero code: 127
```

#

```
#HELLO
FROM rhel6
MAINTAINER xxxxx

#RUN yum -y install wget

RUN yum update -y && yum clean all

#RUN yum -y install tar

RUN curl -OL  http://username:pwd@downloads.datastax.com/enterprise/dse-4.0.3-bin.tar.gz

RUN curl -OL  http://username:pwd@downloads.datastax.com/enterprise/opscenter-4.0.3.tar.gz

RUN echo $PATH

RUN tar -xzvf opscenter-4.0.3.tar.gz

RUN rm *.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

The docker container which you're using does not provide a utility for tar. I tested this using the following;

```
sudo docker run -i -t rhel6 /bin/bash
```

This created an interactive shell for me within Docker using the rhel6 image, from there I can then check in an interactive manner the error which you're seeing;

```
bash-4.1# find / -name tar
bash-4.1# yum list | grep -i tar
upstart.x86_64               0.6.5-13.el6_5.3               @koji-override-0/6.5
```

Both of those commands show that tar is both not installed and not available.

I'm not sure about your reasoning to use rhel, or how rhel works with it's licensing within Docker containers but would it be possible for you to use CentOS, which provides tar as standard;

```
sudo docker run -i -t centos /bin/bash
bash-4.1# yum list | grep -i tar
---snip---
tar.x86_64                               2:1.26-29.el7                   base   
---snip---
```